# Connection string could not be found running azure function and entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, azure, connection-string, azure-functions

I've have an Asp.Net MVC app in one project and I moved my db context file used to connect to Entity Framework into it's own project, so that I can access EF from both my Asp.Net MVC app and my Azure Function apps. But running the Azure Function throws an exception when trying to get the connection string.

> No connection string named 'YogaBandyDatabase' could be found in the application config file.

I tried putting the connection string into the app.config file for the .DataLayer project and I tried putting the connection string into the local.settings.json file and I tried putting the connection string into the portal under application settings connection strings but I'm still getting this exception.

QUESTION - where is it looking for the connection string, it says the application config file? Which one? the one from the .DataLayer project? Did I put it in correctly to the app.config file?

Here is my project structure

[image]

Here is the error in the context file

[image]

Here is my context file in the .DataLayer project

```
namespace YogaBandy2017.Context
{
public class YogabandyContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public YogabandyContext() 
        : base("name=YogaBandyDatabase")
    {

    }

    public YogabandyContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {

    }

    public static YogabandyContext Create()
    {
        return new YogabandyContext();
    }

    public DbSet<YogaBandyError> YogaBandyErrors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<YogaProfile> YogaProfiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<YogaClass> YogaClasses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<YogaSpaceEvent> YogaSpaceEvents { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ReportImage> ReportImages { get; set; }

    public DbSet<ReportProfile> ReportProfiles { get; set; }

    public DbSet<ReportSpace> ReportSpaces { get; set; }
    public DbSet<YogaSpace> YogaSpaces { get; set; }

    public DbSet<YogaSpaceFollower> YogaSpaceFollower { get; set; }

    public DbSet<YogaProfileFollower> YogaProfileFollower { get; set; }

    public DbSet<RegisteredStudent> RegisteredStudents { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
}
```

Here is the local.settings.json file with the connection string (maybe syntax is incorrect)

```
{
 "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
   "AzureWebJobsStorage": "the string",
   "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "",
   "yogabandy2017_RootManageSharedAccessKey_SERVICEBUS": "the string"
 },
 "ConnectionStrings": {
   "YogaBandyDatabase": "the string"
 }
}
```

Here is the connection string in the app.config file for the .DataLayer project

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="YogaBandyDatabase" connectionString="my string" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="YogaBandyErrorDatabase" connectionString="my string" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v13.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? I'm in a similar situation as you now.

Answer (score 0):

This one is a little tricky. Log into the Azure portal and navigate to your Function. Click on the Application Settings link on the Overview tab for your Function. Place your EF connection string under the Connection Strings section.

Comment: funny! I'm not so sure I'm concerned with it working from the portal, I'm more curious to know how to get it working WITHOUT sticking it into the portal. Being that I'm using Visual Studio and publishing it up into Azure from VS I want to maintain everything from VS!

Comment: FYI - I did do this and I still received the same exception

Comment: @user1186050, I'm a one-trick pony on this question. That's all I can think of.